# Apple Script - send "Message (with date/time?)" to imessagebuddy

Tags: applescript

How do I get apple script to include the current time in an imessage sent with apple script?

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Messages"
        set iMessageService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
        set imessagebuddy to buddy "mymessagebuddy@domain.com" of iMessageService
        send "Message" to imessagebuddy
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?  How are you attempting to add the date/time currently?

Comment: Currently I have nothing at all to implement what I want. Just edited to show what I currently have that gets a message sent. But where "message" I want to have current date/time when the script runs.

Comment: [Please have a look at this](https://i.imgur.com/JeG15L3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an *example* of how to add the *time* to the message:

```
set theTime to time string of (current date)

tell application "Messages"
    set iMessageService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
    set imessagebuddy to buddy "mymessagebuddy@domain.com" of iMessageService
    send "Message " & theTime to imessagebuddy
end tell
```

In the OP you said "to include the current time" but in your comment you said "to have current date/time", so if you want the latter, then use the following *example* instead:

```
set theDateTime to (current date) as string

tell application "Messages"
    set iMessageService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
    set imessagebuddy to buddy "mymessagebuddy@domain.com" of iMessageService
    send "Message " & theDateTime to imessagebuddy
end tell
```

---

By the way, if you plan on using **AppleScript** it would behove you to read the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). You can get to it from: **Script Editor** > **Help** > **Show AppleScript Language Guide**

For reference to [**`time string`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCGECID), it's shown under `date` under Class Reference in the AppleScript Language Guide.

For reference to [**`current date`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW39), it's shown under Commands Reference in the AppleScript Language Guide.